# How do you alter the default WordPress thumbnail?

Tags: media-library, thumbnails, images

I have selected 'thumbnail' under 'Apply changes to:', however, nothing seems to happen in either the media library or on the site. I've also tried regenerating the images after making changes, but the result shows the changes being added to the full-size image, not the thumbnail.